# Wix React-Native-Navigation: onPress for custom component button

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, rightbarbuttonitem, onpress, wix-react-native-navigation

I have written a custom right navigation button by following the example given [here](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/blob/master/docs/adding-buttons-to-the-navigator.md#custom-navigation-buttons). However, it seems like the `onNavigatorEvent()` method does not get called anymore when using a custom component. I even tried passing the onPress event as a prop to my custom component but that comes through as `undefined`. Is there something I am missing?

This is how I am passing the onPress prop to the function that's creating the button:

```
Navigation.registerComponent('DoneButton', () => DoneButton);

const DoneButton = ({text, backgroundColor, textColor, onPressAction}) => {
    var containerStyle = [{backgroundColor: backgroundColor, width: 70, height:30, justifyContent:'center', borderRadius:4, shadowColor:'black', shadowOpacity:0.2, shadowRadius:1, shadowOffset:{width:0, height:2}}];            
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity style={containerStyle} onPress={onPressAction}>
            <Text style={[{color:textColor, textAlign: 'center', fontSize:16}]}>
                {text}
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}

_renderDoneButton(){
    this.props.navigator.setButtons({
        rightButtons: [
            {
              id:           'Done'
              component:    'DoneButton',
              passProps:    this._DoneButtonProps(),
            }],
    })
}

_DoneButtonProps(){
    return {
        text:               'Done',
        backgroundColor:    'green',
        textColor:          'white',
        onPressAction:      this._doneAction.bind(this)
    }
}

_doneAction(){
    alert('Done');
}
```

Comment: Hi, Can u plz share some code? the registration, the `function` itself

Comment: @gran33 Okay, adding more code

Comment: @gran33 please refresh and have a look at the updated code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version 1.1.282 you can pass unserializable props to custom buttons, so the onPress method which you are passing should work.

Comment: The props are passed fine. Except for the onPress. When debugging every prop seems valid, but the onPressAction is undefined. Can you provide a working example if possible please.

Comment: What version of RNN do you have?

Comment: I have version 1.1.262.  And the props are being passed through as you said. Unless you were referring specifically to the onPress prop. If so then I will upgrade and test again.

Comment: If that version you specified works for passing the onPress prop, then how were the custom buttons responding to touch event before that? Im sure im missing something here...